# Web Server and Cron Jobs -- Use same Common Files?

Tags: php, cron

I have a website. That is setup like this:

```
/public_html
    index.php
    common.php
    db.php
    /dev
      index.php
      common.php
      db.php
```

`common.php` contains recurring functions.  `Db.php` contains the database connection info.

`common.php` also contains functions to determine weather the page being accessed currently is in 'Dev' or 'Production'.  It then uses this info to call up include files accordingly.

The problem is, I also have some Cron Jobs setup, which call Php Scripts located outside `public_html`.  But none of the includes work, because the functions that dtermine that paths, use `$_SERVER` variables, and rely on pieces of the URL (like the presence of the word '/dev').

So, am I better off just having a separate set of files for my Cron Jobs (database connections and functions) even if they may duplicate the same files in the other parts of the site?

Comment: You could rewrite your crons to use wget or curl and access a page and actually run in a session . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OS environment variables to set the execution environment of your scripts.

Crontab:

```
MYAPP_ENV=production
# min hr dom mon dow command
  0   *  *   *   *   php /var/www/myapp/scripts/cron.php
```

Your scripts:

```
$environment = env('MYAPP_ENV');
```

Comment: i've actually never used environmental variables, so I'll have to do some reading, as this isn't really making much sense to me.  thanks though, i'll take a look!

Comment: OK, so i'm understanding how the environmental variables work in the htaccess files, for setting my 'dev' and 'production' environments, but I still don't see how that helps my cron jobs really..

Comment: In my example above, I set an environment variable on line 1 of crontab. This variable is then available in all scripts executed by crontab.

Comment: I see.  So if I had environmental variables in .htaccess files, where the cron scripts (php files) are located, the crontab wouldn't be able to use those environmental variables?

Comment: No, crontab is executed on the command-line, not within an Apache request, so they are separate. :) However, environment variables that are set globally within the OS can be seen by both.

Comment: Note: if your code defaults to the production environment, you only need to set the environment variable to 'development' on your local development machine(s): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519

Answer (score 0):

You can determine paths relative to common.php instead, using `dirname(__FILE__)` to obtain the full path to common.php, then, relative to that, determine all the other paths. In my experience, this is the most portable way of determining paths, since it doesn't require server or OS cooperation.

From PHP 5.3, you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` to obtain the directory in which the current file resides.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change how you determine environment for starters.  Server (environment) [variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html) are one good approach.  You can set those easily at the vhost level with apache, or even in an htaccess file.

Relative paths and chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); can work into a solution for your path issues.

Seems you understand the issue and your asking permission here to do something that makes you feel dirty :)  Don't duplicate things unnecessarily.  Re-factor your code instead.